# Почему "отовсюду", а не "отовсюда"?

Tags: этимология

Почему в русском языке слово *отовсюду* не поменяло своего окончания наравне с другими:
ст.слав. куду - рус. куда;
ст.слав. туду - рус. туда;
ст.слав. сюду - рус. сюда ?

Comment: «Отовсюду не поменяло своего окончания.» А — повсюду, поскольку и пр.?

Comment: @shampar это старославянское окончание, отвечающее на старославянский вопрос по куду -> повсюду

Comment: @shampar исходя из вышепредставленных мной примеров в русском должно быть  откуда? отовсюда.

Comment: Всюду — наречие, слово неизменяемое, отвечающее на вопрос «где?»; с приставкой — форму сохраняет, и отвечает на вопрос «откуда?».

Comment: отвечало в старославянской речи на вопрос "куду?" в русском языка вопроса "куду" не стало, он преобразился в "куда", а "всюду" должно было статься "всюда", однако кто-то этого не захотел и объявил  "всюду" наречием, точно также как объявил наречием восвояси (въ своя си) воочию (въ очию), вопрос почему?

Comment: Кто-то — это народ? Он не захотел отвечать на "куду?", а  захотел отвечать на "где?"

Comment: Бог его знает, дополню, что "ку" в слове куду, означало краткую форму прилагательного ст.-слав. кую (рус. какую), а вот что или кто такая "ду" и с чем её едят, я без понятий.

Comment: @shampar ну так можно далеко зайти, к примеру до того, что выделение предложного падежа было тоже предложено народом, а не введено М.В. Ломоносовым (которому, впрочем, как и всем нам народное представляется не чуждым)